# Changing the Forms text and Hidden Value by specifying the Form and Field Names

Tags: jquery

```
<form id="dasForm" method="post" action="bootcamp.php">
<input type="text" class="dasName" name="dasName" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" class="dasHandle" name="dasHandle" value="default">
<input value="Submit" id="dasAddThis" class="dasAddThis" type="submit">
</form>

<div class="temp">Temp Link</div>
```

I'm trying to set the values for a text field and a hidden field by specifying the form name and the text and hidden field in the form since there are many form on the page and things may be mixed up if I do not do so.

I'm doing it this way as follows, but nothing changes. If you can see where I go wrong, can you please help me out?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.temp').click(function() {
    $('#dasForm .input[name=dasName]').val('New Name');
    $('#dasForm .input[name=dasHandle]').val('Das New Value');
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate thought is that you are trying to use `input` as a class in your jQuery, when it's not a class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.temp').click(function() {
        $('#dasForm input[name=dasName]').val('New Name');
        $('#dasForm input[name=dasHandle]').val('Das New Value');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Oh! This was the mistake then. I could have sworn the web site where I picked this from did it the same way as in my question.

Comment: The `.` prefix to a selector tells jQuery that you are specifying an element's class - if you're specifying the actual element, you don't need the `.`.

Comment: Sorry they did it like this `$('#dasForm .dasName').val('New Name');` BTW, is this faster/safer or the other one?

Comment: It really doesn't matter - the only difference is that "our" way means it HAS to be an `input` element but the tutorial's way will select any element with a class of "dasName" whether it's an input or not.